# Inner joins from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables (destinations, resorts, hotels and multicentres).
Within the multicentres table i have 36 columns which have relate to the other three tables.
Is there a way I can use inner join to connect the four tables together?

So far I have the below:

```
function getMultiCentres() {
    $db = new Db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM multicentres INNER JOIN destinations ON multicentres.destinationid_1 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_2 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_3 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_4 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_5 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_6 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_7 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_8 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_9 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_10 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_11 = destinations.destinationid AND multicentres.destinationid_12 = destinations.destinationid 

    INNER JOIN resorts ON multicentres.resortid_1 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_2 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_3 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_4 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_5 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_6 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_7 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_8 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_9 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_10 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_11 = resorts.resortid AND multicentres.resortid_12 = resorts.resortid 

    INNER JOIN hotels ON multicentres.hotelid_1 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_2 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_3 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_4 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_5 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_6 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_7 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_8 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_9 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_10 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_11 = hotels.hotelid AND multicentres.hotelid_12 = hotels.hotelid 
     ";
    $multicentres = $db -> select($sql);
    return $multicentres;
}
```

Comment: What is not working with your actual query example?

Comment: It's not bringing back any results

Comment: Your join conditions looks quite strict with all those _AND_  that impose all the ids to correspond... shouldn't you have used _ORs_ into your join clauses?

Comment: My thought behind it was that the multicentres table is to list 12 destintions someone would visit in one holiday (in one row). Therefore, i used the id of the destination in each column and then i would bring through the rest of the information from the destinations table through an inner join

Comment: Slight nitpick, if you have 36 columns try thinking about which of them don't apply to _all_ multicenters, and pulling them into different tables to help normalize your db and reduce the strain on your fingers from typing in 36 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you want to match all the columns but just 1 column from each table.
 So instead of the `AND` operators use `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM multicentres m 
INNER JOIN destinations d
ON d.destination IN (
  m.destination_1, m.destination_2, m.destination_3, m.destination_4, m.destination_5, m.destination_6, 
  m.destination_7, m.destination_8, m.destination_9, m.destination_10, m.destination_11, m.destination_12
) 
INNER JOIN resorts r
ON r.resortid IN (
  m.resortid_1, m.resortid_2, m.resortid_3, m.resortid_4, m.resortid_5, m.resortid_6, 
  m.resortid_7, m.resortid_8, m.resortid_9, m.resortid_10, m.resortid_11, m.resortid_12
) 
INNER JOIN hotels h
ON h.hotelid IN (
  m.hotelid_1, m.hotelid_2, m.hotelid_3, m.hotelid_4, m.hotelid_5, m.hotelid_6, 
  m.hotelid_7, m.hotelid_8, m.hotelid_9, m.hotelid_10, m.hotelid_11, m.hotelid_12
)
```

Also maybe instead of INNER JOINs use LEFT JOINS.